# Add order by default alphabetically for an array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sorting

I have this function :

```
  computed: { 
      availableSystems() {
         const availableSystems = this.systems.filter((sys) => sys && !sys?.active && sys?.enabled) || [];
         availableSystems.sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.name < b.name) { return -1; }
            if (a.name > b.name) { return 1; }
            return 0;
         });
         return availableSystems;
  },
```

But is not working as expected. I have the array of data whithout sort alphabetically. Have you an idea ? Thx in advance

Comment: It would be hard to understand without sufficient data. I'd recommend to add more information...

Comment: Is the `name` property defined? If a or b.name doesn't exist, it won't sort anything

Comment: I also think you should consider breaking your question down to the absolute minimum amount of information needed to help you out. Consider reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
If you consider your question, it has nothing to do with Vue js and the extra filter statement and conditions just adds noise that can make your question more difficult to answer.